# Blank image when I render any frame of animation (eevee)

Tags: rendering, node-editor, camera, eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes

Edit: Still no answer after 1 day :(

Here's the file so that you can directly download and find the problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/182HmbrOHKKe7TOrePJUtYY1iW85J3jim/view?usp=sharing

I'm a beginner so it shouldn't be complicated. I might have missed something reaally obvious

I know several users already had this problem and asked the question here, but I tried a lot of things that worked for other users and it didn't do anything. Even the most basic thing, which is restarting my computer, didn't work either.

What's weird though is that in the rendered view the frames are perfectly visible and doing well, but when I actually try to render any frame I just get a blank png.

Anyway, I need help

Edit: still have the problem :/ I have no idea how to solve it

Edit2: Please :(

[image]

[image]

Comment: you did not provide your file...

Comment: I tried with Blender exchange but it didn't work. Now I used Google drive and it works perfectly. The file is completely provided, anyone can download the project

Comment: I still have the problem btw so if anyone can help by downloading my project and trying to see what's wrong...

Comment: Not sure why your file did not work, but if you append all your scene, objects and camera to a new file, that those works

Comment: I found what was the problem anyway

Answer (score 4):

Ok I found what was the problem a few hours ago, I had the "sequencer" option turned on in Output Properties>PostProcessing
It need to be off for some reason

Thanks this guy
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNtq0e1aEE0&t=184s